# RPGLE Entry list adding leading spaces to string variable

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am testing a new program that passes parameters from a CL to an SQLRPGLE

I declare a total of 16 variables and use CHGVAR to just set values to test the passing of parameter.

```
         PGM

         DCL        VAR(&COMPFR) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(3)
         DCL        VAR(&COMPTO) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(3)
         DCL        VAR(&LOCFR) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(4)
         DCL        VAR(&LOCTO) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(4)
         DCL        VAR(&CLSTFR) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(1)
         DCL        VAR(&CLSTTO) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(1)
         DCL        VAR(&CUSTFR) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(7)
         DCL        VAR(&CUSTTO) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(7)
         DCL        VAR(&ITEMFR) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(20)
         DCL        VAR(&ITEMTO) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(20)
         DCL        VAR(&CLDTFR) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(8)
         DCL        VAR(&CLDTTO) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(8)
         DCL        VAR(&SCDTFR) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(8)
         DCL        VAR(&SCDTTO) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(8)
         DCL        VAR(&CMDTFR) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(8)
         DCL        VAR(&CMDTTO) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(8)

         CHGVAR     VAR(&COMPFR) VALUE('2')
         CHGVAR     VAR(&COMPTO) VALUE('2')
         CHGVAR     VAR(&LOCFR) VALUE('6')
         CHGVAR     VAR(&LOCTO) VALUE('6')
         CHGVAR     VAR(&CLSTFR) VALUE('0')
         CHGVAR     VAR(&CLSTTO) VALUE('9')
         CHGVAR     VAR(&CUSTFR) VALUE('0000000')
         CHGVAR     VAR(&CUSTTO) VALUE('9999999')
         CHGVAR     VAR(&ITEMFR) VALUE('00000000000000000000')
         CHGVAR     VAR(&ITEMTO) VALUE('99999999999999999999')
         CHGVAR     VAR(&CLDTFR) VALUE('00000000')
         CHGVAR     VAR(&CLDTTO) VALUE('99999999')
         CHGVAR     VAR(&SCDTFR) VALUE('00000000')
         CHGVAR     VAR(&SCDTTO) VALUE('99999999')
         CHGVAR     VAR(&CMDTFR) VALUE('00000000')
         CHGVAR     VAR(&CMDTTO) VALUE('99999999')

         CALL       PGM(JALLIB/SBRNTRPT) +
                     PARM(&COMPFR &COMPTO +
                     &LOCFR &LOCTO &CLSTFR &CLSTTO +
                     &CUSTFR &CUSTTO &ITEMFR &ITEMTO +
                     &CLDTFR &CLDTTO &SCDTFR &SCDTTO +
                     &CMDTFR &CMDTTO)


         ENDPGM
```

I then accept the parameters in my RPGLE and build an SQL Statement accordingly. 
Snippet below shows how I accept the parameters

```
// Qualfied parameters data structure defined

    dcl-ds parmsds qualified;
      compfr char(3);
      compto char(3);
      locfr char(4);
      locto char(4);
      clstfr char(1);
      clstto char(1);
      custfr char(7);
      custto char(7);
      itemfr char(20);
      itemto char(20);
      cldtfr char(8);
      cldtto char(8);
      scdtfr char(8);
      scdtto char(8);
      cmdtfr char(8);
      cmdtto char(8);
    end-ds;

    // Prototype and Interface used to pass parmeters from the CL Program

    dcl-pr sbrntrpt extpgm;
      parms likeds(parmsds);
    end-pr;

    dcl-pi sbrntrpt;
      parms likeds(parmsds);
    end-pi;
```

But for some reason, when I debug and check the parms list. One variable, itemfr, is adding two leading blanks to the variable and throwing off the rest of input following that variable

[image]

I have used SNDPGMMSG to verify that the value sent from the CL is accurate but something is wrong when I accepting this large string. I have even tried to just make that string 2 characters longer but then the variable right after, ITEMTO, gets 10 leading blanks spaces added.

The program is pretty simple so far so I am lost as to what is causing this. 
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: In the future, do not paste images. They are impossible to cut and paste from.

Comment: Edited. thanks for the advice

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So what you are doing is passing 16 parameters to a program and receiving a single parameter. It could work today and fail tomorrow depending on how the 16 parameters are arranged in memory. If you are passing 16 parameters, you really need to receive 16 parameters. There are two ways to solve this 1) add each field as a parameter in the RPG program, or 2) combine the fields in the CL program into a single structure.

Receive multiple parameters in the RPG:

```
dcl-pr sbrntrpt extpgm;
  compfr     Char(3);
  compto     Char(3);
  ...
  cmdtto     Char(8);
end-pr;

dcl-pi sbrntrpt;
  compfr     Char(3);
  compto     Char(3);
  ...
  cmdtto     Char(8);
end-pi;
```

-or-

Pass a structure from the CLP

```
PGM

DCL        VAR(&PARMS)  TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(118)
DCL        VAR(&COMPFR) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN( 3) STG(*DEFINED) DEFVAR(&PARMS   1)
DCL        VAR(&COMPTO) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN( 3) STG(*DEFINED) DEFVAR(&PARMS   4) 
DCL        VAR(&LOCFR)  TYPE(*CHAR) LEN( 4) STG(*DEFINED) DEFVAR(&PARMS   7) 
DCL        VAR(&LOCTO)  TYPE(*CHAR) LEN( 4) STG(*DEFINED) DEFVAR(&PARMS  11) 
DCL        VAR(&CLSTFR) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN( 1) STG(*DEFINED) DEFVAR(&PARMS  15) 
DCL        VAR(&CLSTTO) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN( 1) STG(*DEFINED) DEFVAR(&PARMS  16) 
DCL        VAR(&CUSTFR) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN( 7) STG(*DEFINED) DEFVAR(&PARMS  17) 
DCL        VAR(&CUSTTO) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN( 7) STG(*DEFINED) DEFVAR(&PARMS  24) 
DCL        VAR(&ITEMFR) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(20) STG(*DEFINED) DEFVAR(&PARMS  31) 
DCL        VAR(&ITEMTO) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(20) STG(*DEFINED) DEFVAR(&PARMS  51) 
DCL        VAR(&CLDTFR) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN( 8) STG(*DEFINED) DEFVAR(&PARMS  71) 
DCL        VAR(&CLDTTO) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN( 8) STG(*DEFINED) DEFVAR(&PARMS  79) 
DCL        VAR(&SCDTFR) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN( 8) STG(*DEFINED) DEFVAR(&PARMS  87) 
DCL        VAR(&SCDTTO) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN( 8) STG(*DEFINED) DEFVAR(&PARMS  95) 
DCL        VAR(&CMDTFR) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN( 8) STG(*DEFINED) DEFVAR(&PARMS 103)
DCL        VAR(&CMDTTO) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN( 8) STG(*DEFINED) DEFVAR(&PARMS 111)

CHGVAR     VAR(&COMPFR) VALUE('2')
CHGVAR     VAR(&COMPTO) VALUE('2')
CHGVAR     VAR(&LOCFR) VALUE('6')
CHGVAR     VAR(&LOCTO) VALUE('6')
CHGVAR     VAR(&CLSTFR) VALUE('0')
CHGVAR     VAR(&CLSTTO) VALUE('9')
CHGVAR     VAR(&CUSTFR) VALUE('0000000')
CHGVAR     VAR(&CUSTTO) VALUE('9999999')
CHGVAR     VAR(&ITEMFR) VALUE('00000000000000000000')
CHGVAR     VAR(&ITEMTO) VALUE('99999999999999999999')
CHGVAR     VAR(&CLDTFR) VALUE('00000000')
CHGVAR     VAR(&CLDTTO) VALUE('99999999')
CHGVAR     VAR(&SCDTFR) VALUE('00000000')
CHGVAR     VAR(&SCDTTO) VALUE('99999999')
CHGVAR     VAR(&CMDTFR) VALUE('00000000')
CHGVAR     VAR(&CMDTTO) VALUE('99999999')

CALL       PGM(JALLIB/SBRNTRPT) +
            PARM(&PARMS)


ENDPGM
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I always push to have entry data structures in RPG so I can qualify them. But I neglected the CL.

Comment: IMO, individual parms are better, allowing *OMIT and/or *NOPASS to be used.  (Note that *NOPASS can't easily be used from CL)

Comment: There is nothing special to do with *NOPASS, just don't pass it. That works just as well from CL as from RPG.